# Bluetooth pulse oximeter

Tags: android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I am planning to create a small IOT project which includes Raspberry PI, Bluetooth adapter, and Bluetooth pulse oximeter
to show the percent oxygen saturation (spo2) and heart rate (bpm).

I have the following options to do it:

```
    Bluetooth pulse oximeter --->  Bluetooth adapter (for making Bluetooth connection)    ------------------> Raspberry PI (write a script to get the data what oximeter sends over the Bluetooth connection)
```

**or**

```
    Bluetooth pulse oximeter provide support to connect android free app SPO2       ----> Android phone running free SPO2 app  (hack this app and get oximeter data)-------> Bluetooth adapter ------> Raspberry PI
```

Main problem: How to get data from Bluetooth pulse oximeter (third party device). They don't have public API exposed and i don't know how they are sending the data.

Is there anyone who have already done this kind of IoT example which involves reading data through bluetooth connection through logging or other methods?

If anyone have experience, could you please explain me the exact devices you used for this project and how you retrieved the data.

If you haven't done this kind of work, still you can suggest the approach to build this kind of project?

Comment: You have to reverse engineer the protocol and commands that the oximeter accepts. There is no single answer that will cover all devices. But if  you have a particular device then google it and you may find that someone has already reverse engineered it. Alternatively you can approach the vendor and request a copy of their API documentation. They may or may not make that available to third party developers depending on their policy.

Comment: Why not post the oximeter manufacturer and model number?  What have you done to try to acquire the API?  Nonin has USB oximeters and publishes the API.

Comment: @user906221 - have you found any solution? I have same requirement from client.

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth Low Energy does have set of profiles and services.

One for Pulse Oximeter profile, and another for the service.

Once you implement the Profile, Service, Characteristic and Descriptors, You can connect from a smartphone application and read the SpO2 readings or even notified when the value changes.

References:

- [Pulse Oximeter Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/pulse-oximeter-profile-1-0/)
- [Pulse Oximeter Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/pulse-oximeter-service-1-0/).